# Input of enums to switch statment outcomes

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

So here I am asking a user for an input of hit, stand, surrender, or quit. I have these as enums, along with NOTVALID.

```
enum Decisions

{
    HIT, STAND, SURRENDER, QUIT, PLAY, NOTVALID;
    // NOTVALID is used to re-ask to play again
}
```

So, if a user puts for example "blah" instead of one of the valid options, I want it to consider it as NOTVALID and carry out the code in the switch statement that is for NOTVALID. How can I do this? As it is, when I run the program it returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant BlackJack.Decisions.BLAH
```

What can I do to make NOTVALID anything that isn't one of the other enums?

```
System.out.println("Do you want to hit, stand, surrender, or quit?");

        String decisionInput;

        decisionInput = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        decision = Decisions.valueOf(decisionInput);

        switch (decision)
        {
            case HIT: 
                Random playerCard = new Random();

                cardPick = playerCard.nextInt(13);

                playerSum = playerSum + getCardValue(cardPick);

                System.out.println("Card: " + (Card.values()[cardPick]) + ". The sum of your hand is: " + playerSum + "."); 

                System.out.println("The hole card was " + (Card.values()[cardPick2]) + ". The house has: " + houseSum + ".");

                findWinner(playerSum, houseSum, decision);

                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Type PLAY or QUIT.");

                decision = Decisions.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());

                break;

            case STAND:
            case SURRENDER:

                findWinner(playerSum, houseSum, decision);

                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Type PLAY or QUIT.");

                decision = Decisions.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());

                break;

            case QUIT:

                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");

                System.exit(0);

                break;

            case NOTVALID:

                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again: hit, stand, surrender, or quit?");

                decision = Decisions.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());

            }   
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new method that returns `NOTVALID` for unrecognized input. The most concise way is to catch the IllegalArgumentException that is being thrown, as such.

```
enum Decisions{
     HIT, STAND, SURRENDER, QUIT, PLAY, NOTVALID;

     public static Decisions asDecision(String input) {
         try {
             return Decisions.valueOf(input);
         } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
             return Decisions.NOTVALID;
         }
     }
}
```

If that offends your sensibilities for the use of `try..catch`, you can do it manually yourself.

```
enum Decisions{
         HIT, STAND, SURRENDER, QUIT, PLAY, NOTVALID;

         public static Decisions asDecision(String input) {
             for(Decisions d : values()) {
                 if(d.name().toLowerCase().equals(input.toLowerCase()) {
                     return d;
                 }
             }
             return Decisions.NOTVALID;
         }
    }
```

Either way, use the new method instead.

Without being allowed to define new methods, you could surround your assignment in a `try..catch`, as such:

```
    String decisionInput;
    decisionInput = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    try{
        decision = Decisions.valueOf(decisionInput);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        decision = Decisions.NOTVALID;
    }
    // Rest of your code...
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this? This is for a class, and having not yet been taught how to "make" methods, I could probably get points off for this even if its more efficient (which it obviously is).

Comment: Sure, edited post with new approach. If you can't use try..catch either, you can't really use `valueOf` because it may throw the exception. In that case, just switch on the input String instead of an enum and have a `default` case for invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default:` instead of NOTVALID. It's similar to `else` where every other case, it will default to that logic.

```
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again: hit, stand, surrender, or quit?");
    decision = Decisions.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and it returned the same error as I mentioned in my post, unfortunately.